# Is this possible in SSRS? Stored procedure returns dynamic number of columns, how to show in table?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that returns a dynamic number of columns (usernames). Is there a way to create a SSRS report to display the dynamic number of columns?

Thanks.

edit: stored procedure results are simple, they look like

```
Date    UserName1 Username2 Username3 etc. (dynamic #)
--------------------------------------
1/1/20  10        33        45
1/1/20  20        NULL      55
```

Comment: I wouldn't think you that you could, but my SSRS is a little rusty.  Is there any chance you can alter the layout of your proc's result set to give you a properly normalized table with users populating a single column?  You could use a matrix then, to show the data with a dynamic number of columns.

Comment: Ryan B is correct. SSRS expects the results of a dataset to always return the same columns. Edit you question to show some sample data and the proc that creates your current results. There is a good chance that you will only require a simple query and then let SSRS do the work of pivoting your users into columns.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I'm going to rewrite the SP then figure out how to display it in SSRS, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need you dataset output to look something like this.

```
UserName   Date        Amount
UserName1  2020-01-01  10
UserName1  2020-01-02  20
UserName2  2020-01-01  33
UserName3  2020-01-01  45
UserName3  2020-01-02  55
```

Then all you need to do is add a Matrix control to your report. From the Report Data pane, drag the `Date` Column to the "Rows" placeholder on the matrix, drag `UserName` to "columns" and `Amount` to "Data".

That's it. Run the report and your output will look like your original stored proc results.